# How to get data from different collections in firebase from react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So i have 2 collections

1 collection is 'users'. There i have documents (objects) with property 'profile', that contains string. It's id of profile, that is stored in other collection 'roles' as document.

So i'm trying to get this data, but without success. Is there exist join method or something like that? Or i must use promise for getting data from collection roles, and then assign it with agent?

```
async componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .orderBy('lastName')
      .onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges()

        const agents = this.state.agents
        for (const change of changes) {
          if (change.type === 'added') {
            const agent = {
              id: change.doc.id,
              ...change.doc.data()
            }

            await firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection('roles')
              .doc(change.doc.data().profile).get().then( response => {
                //when i get response i want to set for my object from above this val 
                agent['profile'] = response.data().profile
                //after that i want to push my 'agent' object to array of 'agents'
                agents.push(agent)
                console.log(agent)
                }
              )
          }
        }

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          agents: agents
        })
      })
  }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Or is no data being returned?

Comment: i cant receive data cause i cant wait for it! it's async requests. if i clg response.data().profile - i see that everything ok, but if i clg agent['profile'] i see promise with undefined

Comment: You need to make componentDidMount() async. `async componentDidMount()`, You'll also need to use `await` `firebase..collection('users')...` and `await firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection('roles')...`

Comment: thx i'll try it!

Comment: Also, Do not use `changes.Foreach` change to `for (const change of changes)` That way you can use `await` for your second firebase call.

Comment: unfortunately i have some issues. Error says that i cant use await outside async func in firebase....'roles', so can you give as a reply fixed code with right solution please? and i'l mark as solved

Comment: Can post your most recent code and some mock data, I'll have a look at it more closely so I can come up with a solution.

Comment: @Philip i have updated my post for very new code. Added extra comments. There is no dummy data, the question is about how to organize code request. Help please:)

Comment: Oh, You need to add `async` to `.onSnapshot(async snapshot => {` then you can use `await firebase.firestore().collection('roles')`

Comment: @Philip i've update my code in question post. but i'm facing with parsing errors `Line 42:  Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function` please note where is mistake?

Comment: You need to go back to `for (const change of changes)` then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To do async operation on array of objects you can use promise.all, i have given a example below that is similar to your use case where multiple async operation has to be done

```
  const all_past_deals = await Promise.all(past_deals.map(async (item, index) => {
     const user = await Users.get_user_info(item.uid);

    const dealDetails = await Deals.get_deal_by_ids(user.accepted_requests || []);

    const test = await Users.get_user_info(dealDetails[0].uid);
return test
 }))

 }
```

This way you can get  data from once api call  and make other api call with the obtained data